# método test de objeto New RegExp regresa false con expresión regular

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente duda:
Estoy realizando una validación con una expresión regular
Tengo la siguiente expresión regular que permite escribir números y dos números decimales

```
let exp = new RegExp('^\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,2})*(,\d+)?$')
console.log(exp.test(9))
```

Pero al realizar pruebas el método test regresa false, lo cual no comprendo porque es un numero, realice la prueba en esta página para probar expresiones regulares https://regexr.com/ y aquí si hace match si escribo un numero 9, cuál es la diferencia o por qué el método test esta fallando con el 9 solo en JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estás usando el constructor con cadena necesitas escapar las barras.
Esto debería funcionarte:

```
let exp = new RegExp('^\\d{1,10}(\\.\\d{0,2})*(,\\d+)?$')
```

También podrías usar el constructor con la expresión regular literal para evitar tener que escaparla:

```
let exp = new RegExp(/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,2})*(,\d+)?$/)
```

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias